# Babel Not working for imports from node_modules

Tags: babeljs, rollup, rollupjs

I just discovered RollUP and I am stuck with an issue where Babel does not run for imports from node_modules.

Here is an example:

#### My Javascript Code

```js
import { _map } from "@varunsridharan/js-vars"
const myarray = _map.call([1,2,3,4],(x)=> x * 2);
console.log(myarray);
```

#### Rollup Config

```js
import { babel } from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import { uglify } from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';
import filesize from 'rollup-plugin-filesize';
import visualizer from 'rollup-plugin-visualizer';

export default {
    input: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        file: './dist/myfile.min.js',
        format: 'iife',
        plugins: [
            uglify( { mangle: true } ),
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        nodeResolve(),
        babel(),
        filesize(),
        visualizer()
    ]
};
```

When I run `rollup -c` in **CLI** I get this output:

[image: https://s2.do-spaces.com/2020/Sep/30/1601479998-194.jpg]

```
babelHelpers: 'bundled' option was used by default. It is recommended to configure this option explicitly, read more here: https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/babel#babelhelpers
  198 |          * Array Related Vars.
  199 |          */
> 200 |         const Arr = Array;
      | ^ Unexpected token: keyword «const»
  201 |         const _Arrayprop = Arr.prototype;
  202 |         const _filter = _Arrayprop.filter;
  203 |         const _push = _Arrayprop.push;
[!] (plugin uglify) Error: Unexpected token: keyword «const»
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: keyword «const»
    at JS_Parse_Error.get (eval at <anonymous> (E:\localhost\www\javascript\dizzle\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:18:1), <anonymous>:69:23)
    at reportError (E:\localhost\www\javascript\dizzle\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:107:11)
    at reportClientError (E:\localhost\www\javascript\dizzle\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:87:10)
    at execFunction (E:\localhost\www\javascript\dizzle\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:157:5)
    at execHelper (E:\localhost\www\javascript\dizzle\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:139:5)
    at execMethod (E:\localhost\www\javascript\dizzle\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:143:5)
    at process.<anonymous> (E:\localhost\www\javascript\dizzle\node_modules\jest-worker\build\workers\processChild.js:64:7)
    at process.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emit (internal/child_process.js:876:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:21)
```

Based on the output i was able to understand that babel did not run for the imported modules. so i checking the options provided for rollup babel plugin @ (https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/babel) and found that it has ***`include`*** AND ***`exclude`*** options and i tried with the below config

```js
babel( {
    include: [ "node_modules/@varunsridharan/*/**", "./src/**" ],
    exclude: "node_modules/**",
} ),
```

Still, nothing happened so I tried without ***`./src/**`*** in babel include config and found that babel is not running in my main javascript file which imports the node_modules's file

Node Module Project Link: https://github.com/varunsridharan/js-vars